# How to get summary into an output in Python-Behave

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

This is a summary of the tests after it runs:

```
1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
3 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
```

I want to be able to print it into a file or have access to it from the modules. The behave documentations doesn't have an argument that makes the summary print into a a different output.

Comment: no offense, but I'm gonna pull an **rtfm** on you here... there's a command line option `-o` to print output to file instead of stdout

Comment: Yeah but the summary doesn't go into the output. Only the scenarios

Comment: how did this summary get printed in this case then?

Comment: that's what i'm trying to figure out. If there is a module i can access, where i can handle that summary after the test finished running

Comment: **rtfm** [`--summary`](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#cmdoption--summary)

Comment: Again, by default it prints the summary into the console. I'm trying to make a report, where i can grab that summary and put it into my template. pass failed scenarios can be handled  EXCEPT summary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132721/discussion-between-aaron-and-teddybear123).

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

In the script or somewhere you trigger you test, why not simply do a

`behave -o out_file > file_to_save_summary`

Comment: Using `>` will not print to the screen. Using `tee` make the screen print colorless. I think the question is asking how to log everything to an output file in a "behavc" way.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty "output" folder in your behave folder. Also create a file "behave.ini" and put it in your behave folder:

Here is the content of your "behave.ini" file:

```
    [behave]
    junit: true
    junit_directory: <route_to_behave_folder>/output/
    stderr_capture=False
    stdout_capture=True
```